Is $2\uparrow\uparrow\infty + 3$ divisible by a prime number?
Define power tower using Knuth's arrow: $$a\uparrow\uparrow b=\left.a^{a^{a^{...^a}}}\right\}b\text{ layers}$$
It can be proved that for any positive integers $a, n, m\ \ $,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a \uparrow\uparrow n \mod m$ exists. So we can define oeis.org/A245970
$$a\uparrow\uparrow \infty \equiv\lim_{n \to \infty} a \uparrow\uparrow n \mod m $$
Question
Is there a prime number $p$ that:
$$2\uparrow\uparrow \infty\equiv-3 \mod p$$
Known results
It can be proved that no prime number $p$ satisfy $2\uparrow\uparrow \infty\equiv-1 \mod p$, in other words, $2\uparrow\uparrow \infty+1$ is not divisible by any prime number. Sometimes there exists a factor but very large. For example, the smallest prime factor of $3\uparrow\uparrow \infty+4$ is $61094071$. I guess $2\uparrow\uparrow \infty+3$ is this case, but it is more interesting if it has no factors.
I checked $p<3*10^{10}$ but have not found a factor of $2\uparrow\uparrow \infty +3$
Python code:
from sympy import totient, isprime
import multiprocessing as mp

a = 2
b = 3  
threadnum=22
assert(isprime(threadnum+1))
start=2
end=30000000000
infon=3000000000

def towermod(a, m):
    if m == 1:
        return 0
    tm = totient(m)
    return pow(a, int(tm + towermod(a, tm)), int(m))

def check(p, b):
    if not isprime(p):
        return False
    m1 = towermod(a, p)
    m2 = b
    return ((m1 + m2) % p) == 0

def check_prime_class(args):
    mod_class, b, start, end = args
    for p in range(start, end):
        if(p%infon==0):
            print(f"info:{mod_class} finished {p}")
        if p % (threadnum+1) == mod_class and isprime(p):
            if check(p, b):
                print(f"Found factor of {a}^^inf + {b}: {p}")
                return p  
    return None

def find_prime(b, start, end):
    with mp.Pool(processes=threadnum) as pool:
        args = [(mod_class, b, start, end) for mod_class in range(1,threadnum+1)]
        results = pool.map(check_prime_class, args)  

    for result in results:
        if result:
            print(f"Found factor of {a}^^inf + {b}: {result}")

    print("No factor found")
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_prime(b,start,end)


Update on 2024.10.26
@Adam P. Goucher has checked $p<10^{13}$ using his much faster program without finding a factor

If $p \equiv 2 \pmod3$ and $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod8$ (i.e. $p \equiv 17, 23 \pmod{24}$) then $-3$ isn't a quadratic residue but $2$ is, so $-3$ can't be a power of $2$ modulo those primes.

Thanks, this will reduce 25% useless calculation of this program. Can this method go further?

@DanielWeber in fact it suffices to just know -3 is not a quadratic residue since we take 2 to an even power.

Is there any motivation behind this question? As someone not from number theory, this looks wild.

if the $+3$ was changed to a $-3$, then this would imply that the Ackermann function is eventually a multiple of $p$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Definition:_as_m-ary_function

This question comes from something like "Is there any prime numbers near Graham's number".
Changing +3 to other numbers usually lead to small factors. For example, 2↑↑∞-3 has two factors 13 and 71 below 10^6. However there are many other numbers has no known factors below 10^7 like 2↑↑∞+3:  2↑↑∞-87, -39, +21, +51, +93 ...

@hzy You should include this motivation in the question.

What kind of motivation? Obviously it has no practical value and it is just for fun. And I don't know what field of mathematics this is related to.

@DanielWeber Surely, $-3$ should be a quadratic residue modulo $p$ anyway, which reduces to $p\equiv 1\pmod3$.

There's actually a sequence at oeis related to this question: https://oeis.org/A152177 "Smallest prime factor of $G+n$, where $G$ is any sufficiently large power tower of $3$, e.g., Graham's number."

@IlyaBogdanov In addition to $-3$ being a square $\mod p$, it needs also be a fourth power, eighth power, and so on. This is equivalent to requiring that:
$(-3)^r = 1 \mod p$
where we have expressed $p = r 2^k + 1$ with $r$ odd. Moreover, we can apply this test before we've checked that $p$ is prime, as anything that passes this must be a strong probable prime (in the sense of Miller-Rabin) to base $-3$; most composite numbers will be discarded by this test.

@hzy I've increased the lower bound to 10^13 using the following code; it took about a day on my laptop to exhaust this range: https://gitlab.com/hatsya/open-source/cpads/-/blob/master/test/cpu/powermod.cpp

Your program is much faster. Mine is 10^11 per day

Does this construction equip $a \uparrow\uparrow \infty$ with the structure of a profinite integer? At least, I'd think it would. I kinda wanna see someone better at maths than me explore the consequences of this observation.

Yes, since for any $m$ $a\uparrow\uparrow n$ converges to a fixed value mod $m$, $a\uparrow\uparrow \infty$ gives a well-defined element of the profinite completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

The simplest possible heuristic is that the probability that this happens for a given $p$ is $1/p$ which means the expected number of such $p$ up to $X$ is $\log \log X$. So the expected number of solutions up to $10^{13}$ is a bit more than $3$. So not finding any solutions may just represent a small coincidence.  One can try to find a more sophisticated heuristic but I don't think they would make the prediction different from $C  \log \log X$ for some constant $C$ which would perhaps make this coincidence slighlty less surprising.

In fact I agree with you. I have tested many other numbers other than +3. There are ~6 numbers without known factors in +-100 range

@WillSawin: As noted by Adam P. Goucher in a comment above, one should restrict the heuristic to the primes $p$ modulo which $-3$ is a power of $2$. Such primes are listed in https://oeis.org/A256396 and they include https://oeis.org/A001122 as a subsequence.

@MaxAlekseyev There is not much point in doing that unless one know, or has a different heuristic for, an asymptotic for the number of such primes up to $X$, weighted by the inverse of the order of $2$ modulo $p$.

@MaxAlekseyev I don't think that affects the heuristic at all: amongst the primes for which $p - 1$ has a 2-adic valuation of $k$, the proportion of primes $p$ for which $-3$ is a $2^k$th residue is $2^{-k}$ but that's exactly counterbalanced by the fact that for those primes the probability of success is $(2^k)/(p - 1)$.

@WillSawin: On large scale - yes, but your statement "the expected number of solutions up to $10^{13}$ is a bit more than $3$" is a bit too optimistic for that reason.

@AdamP.Goucher: My point is that some large fraction of primes have zero probability of success, and thus should better be excluded from estimation.

@MaxAlekseyev If by "too optimistic" you mean "predicts too high a value for the number of such primes" then you haven't given reason to think this heuristic is too optimistic. You're of course right that one can exclude primes that have zero probability of success, but as Adam P. Goucher points out, one should then also account for the fact that the other primes often have a greater probability of success if the iterated power of $2$ is selected randomly from the powers of $2$, which are a set containing $-3$ that might have smaller size than the set of all residues.

How much does this affect the heuristic? The simplest calculation suggests not at all, that the two effects precisely cancel out, as Adam P. Goucher also pointed out. This is part of why I gave the simple heuristic I did and not a more complicated one that would turn out the same. Of course it's possible that some number-theoretic fact about such primes leads to a different estimate (higher or lower) but this still has to be shown.
